# Determine attributes value with another attribute of the same element

Tags: jquery

In HTML I have this :

```
<div id="content">
    what is inside
</div>
<a title='content'>inside my link</a>
```

With JQuery, I would like to add an attribute to the a element whose value is the value of the element referred in the title value of the a element.

I thought about that but obviously $(this) is not what I think it is :

```
$('a').attr('myNewAttribute', $('#' + $(this).attr('title')).text().trim());
```

myNewAttribute is empty

Answer (score 2):

you need to use a different variant of [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr-attributeName-functionindex--attr) here.

```
$('a').attr('myNewAttribute', function(){
    return $('#' + $(this).attr('title')).text().trim()
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/9njqj/)